# jquery ajax load each post

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, load

I'm working on a wordpress theme with ajax load of some content from featured posts that will be displayed on homepage after a click or other trigger on post image.

Basiclly its something like this:

```
<ul id="posts">
<li class="post">
    <a href="post_url" class="image_link"><img src="images/featured_image.jpg" /><a href="#">
    <a href="#">title</a>
    <div class="ajax_loaded_info"></div>
</li>
<li class="post">
    <a href="post_url" class="image_link"><img src="images/featured_image.jpg" /><a href="#">
    <a href="#">title</a>
    <div class="ajax_loaded_info"></div>
</li>
<li class="post">
    <a href="post_url" class="image_link"><img src="images/featured_image.jpg" /><a href="#">
    <a href="#">title</a>
    <div class="ajax_loaded_info"></div>
</li>
</ul>
```

The jquery code is like this:

```
$(".image_link").click(function () {
    $(".ajax_loaded_info").load($(this).attr("href") + " .title");
});
```

It does success loading the content but it shows the same content (of the last post) for all the posts..

I tried to look for a solution and try some stuff wuthout success..
Hope you guys will help me out in here.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go, a simple sub query with the 'this', doesnt look like much changed, but try it :)

```
$(".image_link").each(function(){
    $(this).click(function () {
        $(".ajax_loaded_info",this).load($(this).attr("href") + " .title");
    });
})
```

Comment: it doesnt work :(
maybe the code is misleading.. should i post the real code?